# executing default fault sequence error code 303001 wso2 esb

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

i have a proxy service that call a web service . sometimes it send out error code 303001 and after refresh it work again . my mind of refresh is i open admin panel in list of service choose design view of my service and click next next finish. after that service work correctly and after 1 hour it throw out error code
my service :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
   name="BillVerification"
   transports="https,http"
   statistics="disable"
   trace="disable"
   startOnLoad="true">
<target>
  <inSequence>
     <class name="org.sample.mediators.citydi.HashMediatorCityDI"/>
     <log level="full" category="FATAL">
        <property name="fprever" value="justyou"/>
     </log>
     <property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING"
               value="true"
               scope="axis2"
               type="STRING"/>
     <send>
        <endpoint>
           <address uri="http://checkbill2.citydi.net/CheckBill.asmx?wsdl" format="soap12">
              <suspendOnFailure>
                 <initialDuration>100000000</initialDuration>
                 <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
                 <maximumDuration>100000000</maximumDuration>
              </suspendOnFailure>
           </address>
        </endpoint>
     </send>
     <log level="full" category="FATAL">
        <property name="send1" value="send1"/>
     </log>
  </inSequence>
  <outSequence>
     <log level="full">
        <property name="beforeSENDout" value="2"/>
     </log>
     <send/>
     <log level="full" category="FATAL">
        <property name="send2" value="send2"/>
     </log>
  </outSequence>
</target>
<publishWSDL uri="http://checkbill2.citydi.net/CheckBill.asmx?wsdl"/>
<description/>
</proxy>
```

Comment: You shouldn't be adding any mediators after the send mediator. Can you remove all the Log mediators after the send mediator and check. Also a full stack-trace might be helpful to debug the issue.

Comment: The error code  303001 [1] seems to indicate that the there is a issue with the address endpoint. Can you verify that the endpoint is active at all time [1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB451/Error+Handling+and+Error+Codes

Comment: yes jason it is active always. do it have any problem with version of soap ?

Comment: i insert this logs mediator after i saw problem .

Comment: Can you enable wirelogs and share the logs? You can refer this : http://mytecheye.blogspot.com/2013/09/wso2-esb-all-about-wire-logs.html

Answer (score 1):

303001 = Address Endpoint is not ready to connect

Perhaps because of a corporate proxy / firewall ?

You'r wrong thinking your endpoint is active always : use a named endpoint instead of your anonymous one and have a look to wso2 web console : I guess it will be deactivated (the "action" become "Switch on")

In your case, with an anonymous endpoint, when you edit / save your proxy, the endpoint is switched on.

If you don't want your endpoint to be suspended add something like this :

```
<suspendOnFailure>
    <errorCodes>-1</errorCodes>
    <initialDuration>0</initialDuration>
    <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
    <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
</suspendOnFailure>
```

If you don't want your endpoint to manage a specific timeout, add something like this :

```
<markForSuspension>
    <errorCodes>-1</errorCodes>
    <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
    <retryDelay>0</retryDelay>
</markForSuspension>
```

Comment: you are right . i used a anonymous endpoint and it switched off after many transaction , i change it to named endpoint and it have worked correctly. tanx